# Find products by category - custom query

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to list products in categories /Computers, Laptops, Printers ../ on home page but for some reason query doesn't return any results. I saw other similar topics in the forum, but none helped.

```php
// ProductRepository

public function findByCategory(int $page = 1, array $category []): Paginator
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->addSelect('c')
            ->leftJoin('p.category', 'c')
            ->where('c.name = :name')
            ->setParameter('name', $category);

        return (new Paginator($qb))->paginate($page);
    }


// HomeController

public function index(int $page, ProductRepository $productRepository,
                          CategoryRepository $categoryRepository)
    {
        $category = new Category();
        $categories = $categoryRepository->findBy(['name' => $category->getName()]); // 'name' => 'Computers' or 'Laptops' or 'Printers'

        $products = $productRepository->findByCategory($page, $categories);

        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', [
            'paginator' => $products
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Can Product have more than one category?  (findby return an array of categories)

Comment: What is `Paginator` ? The Bundle from KnpLabs ?

Comment: @AndreaManzi Nope, many products have one category - ManyToOne relation

Comment: why don't use findOneBy istead of findBy?

Comment: I think this way is wrong, in the index page you have no category sent, so you can't do findby if you don't have the category to filter

Comment: Just wanted to point out that passing an array of category names and then trying to use it as a string is not going to end well.  Might want to take a step back and get yourself an IDE of some sort.  These sorts of errors will be flagged.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you create an object

```
$category = new Category();
```

and $category->getName() is empty

```
$categories = $categoryRepository->findBy(['name' => $category->getName()]); // 'name' => 'Computers' or 'Laptops' or 'Printers'
```

then no categories were found by `findby`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `Paginator` in the repository which goes against the purpose of the separation of concerns.

A repository should be used only for querying.

`Paginator` is not used that way. To get that service, you don't create a new object, but get it from services such as `$paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');`

Then, it is used that way :

```
$products = $paginator->paginate($query, $page, $limit);
```

`$query` being the query.

You need to change your repository to :

```
public function findByCategory(int $page = 1, array $category [])
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->addSelect('c')
        ->leftJoin('p.category', 'c')
        ->where('c.name = :name')
        ->setParameter('name', $category);

    // $qb is actually a QueryBuilder. You need a Query
    return $qb->getQuery();
}
```

And now, in your controller :

```
public function index(int $page, ProductRepository $productRepository,
                      CategoryRepository $categoryRepository)
{
    $category = new Category();
    $categories = $categoryRepository->findBy(['name' => $category->getName()]); // 'name' => 'Computers' or 'Laptops' or 'Printers'

    $productsQuery = $productRepository->findByCategory($page, $categories);

    $products = $paginator->paginate($productsQuery, $page);
    return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', [
        'paginator' => $products
    ]);
}
```

Comment: $category->getName() can't find any categories

Answer (score 0):

You've already loaded your `Category` so you can pass it directly to the query, without having to explicitly search by category name:

```
public function findByCategory(int $page = 1, array $category): Paginator
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->where('p.category = :category')
        ->setParameter('category', $category);

    return (new Paginator($qb))->paginate($page);
}
```

This will work when passing an array when there's just one element, but if you can search among multiple categories you'll have to change the operator:

```
->where('p.category IN (:category)')
```

Comment: in controller what should be second parameter for this function?

Comment: @whiskey_ The `$categories` variable as you had it, but take note of what @Andrea pointed out, your search didn't return any result because `getName()` was empty after instancing. You can for example `$categories = $categoryRepository->findByName('Laptops');`

Comment: With static way query works like a charm but trying to make it dynamic because have navigation tab for each one category. And yes understood my mistake.

Comment: @whiskey_ How are you passing the parameter? Have you checked that you get the expected value?